# What does "Oeuf" mean?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

When I load into my dressing room in my house in GTA V I get the word "Oeuf" across some of my characters clothing not all just some of them, when I load out it disappears. What is this? Everything else in the game works fine.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if it has a different meaning in GTA V, but 
œuf in French means *egg*.

Comment: And we're not talking a clothing brand label right?

Comment: Looks like a glitch and there's a few different things appearing: http://www.reddit.com/r/GrandTheftAutoV/comments/2z4ws0/saved_my_outfit_then_this_happened/